# Exception in SharpDX.dll

Tags: c#, exception, gpu, monogame

I'm working on a school project with four others.
We're writing a game in C# and Monogame.
They pass around the source code without any problems, but I cannot run the program. I get this error on 1 out of 5 computers.

I've been researching, but can't seem to find an answer of how to fix this.

Visual studio gives the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'SharpDX.SharpDXException' occurred in SharpDX.dll
>
> Additional information: HRESULT: [0x887A0005], Module: [SharpDX.DXGI], ApiCode: [DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_REMOVED/DeviceRemoved], Message: GPU-enhedsforekomsten er blevet suspenderet. Brug GetDeviceRemovedReason til at bestemme den relevante handling.

I have Nvidia SLI GT cards, and I'm afraid that's what's causing the problem.
I have no problem with other projects.

Edit:
Okay, after having solved this forever ago, and totally forgetting to write it here, here's what I recall I did:
The error was thrown because I was trying to use something outside of the bounds of the sprite sheet. Fixing that, fixed the issue. Weird how some cards react.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are right. The problem is caused by your graphic card:

here is a [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which explains your error.

"DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_REMOVED
0x887A0005

The video card has been physically removed from the system, or a driver upgrade for the video card has occurred. The application should destroy and recreate the device. For help debugging the problem, call ID3D10Device::GetDeviceRemovedReason."

Comment: I have the newest version of the nvidia driver, and I have tested games with my SLI, and all seems to work fine. It's only the projects that's giving problems. I also fail the see how to fix the problem from that link. I found it too in my research.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Figured this crap out after 2 hours. You have to go to your projects bin folder and delete all the .dll files with the word "Sharp" in it. Once thats done DO NOT build your code again, just run it. It should work.

If you build the code again, C# will generate the .dlls for you.

Let me know if you found any other better solution. Thanks

EDIT: You also have to copy all the files from the Bin of another working Monogame into the bin of your game. Sample game is found at https://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/downloads/get/722128.